# PHP passing values to variables in included files

Tags: php, variables, include, scope

I have a php file (**article.php**) with variables holding content and an include reference to a template holding the html structure (**template.php**).

```
<?php
$headline = 'Headline';
$author = 'Author';
$paragraph = 'Text';
include 'template.php';
?>
```

This is **template.php** noted above. It includes **blockTemplate.php**. (More on that, below.):

```
<html>
   <body>
      <?php include 'blockTemplate.php'; ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is **blockTemplate.php**. It has variables, the values to which I want to provide in **article1.php**, (the top level file):

```
<h1>Title: <?php $headline ?></h1>
<h2>Author: <?php $author ?></h2>
<p>Text: <?php $paragraph ?></p>
```

Here's the output I should be getting from article1.php:

## Title: Headline

### Author: Author

Text: text

Here's the output I am getting. Note the variables didn't get included:

## Title:

### Author

Text:

**Question: how can I pass values in article1.php to the variables in included blockTemplate.php?**  Is what's happening the included files are being processed before inclusion so that contain no variables by the time they are included?

Comment: the code you posted works fine.

Comment: The code looks fine, turn your error reporting on and see if something went wrong somewhere else.

Comment: included files are placed into variable scope of whatever the include directive is placed in - it's as if the contents of the included file had been copied/pasted directly into that spot.

Comment: did you tries to include the template.php which later includes blockTemplate.php?

Comment: this is the correct way of rendering html files. One small recommendation; just use assosiative arrays; let your users/designers know what they have via a print_r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<h1>Title: <?php echo $headline ?></h1>
<h2>Author: <?php echo $author ?></h2>
<p>Text: <?php echo $paragraph ?></p>
```

That works for me

Comment: Yest, that must be it. Everybody missed the missing echoes :)

Comment: I just realized that. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, this code is vulnerable to XSS injection. To fix it (to escape output variables) you must wrap every variable in htmlspecialchars() call.

Comment: If it sounds like a lot of work to you, try some templating system, like [Nette\Latte](http://doc.nette.org/en/templating) or [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. In my include.php I had a line like,

```
echo '<form id="frm"><input type="hidden" id="Variable" valve=$>Variable</form>'
```

Which PHP should evaluated but didn't. So after reading the post above from Xare I tried,

```
echo '<form id="frm"><input type="hidden" id="Variable" valve=$Variable></form>';
```

Removing my $Variable from the single quotes fixed it.